# Mixed Nash Equilibria

Tags: matrices, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Does it hold for all bi-matrix games that all mixed Nash equilibria have the same
expected pay-off ? Or is it necessary that the game is zero-sum ? Finally how can I see and how is it used that the equilibrium must be mixed and not pure (I doubt that this holds though) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In zero-sum all equilibria have the same payoff.

In non-zero-sum, all equilibria with the same support have the same payoff. As a result, all completely mixed equilibria have the same payoff (why? hint: indifference).

However, there might be equilibria with different supports that have different payoffs. For example, consider a $3\times 3$ games whose payoffs are zero except on the diagonal. The payoffs for Player 1 on the diagonal are $2,1,1$ and for Player 2 are $1,2,1$. This game has 7 equilibria: 3 pure, 3 where each player mixes only two actions and one completely mixed equilibrium with very different payoffs (ranging from $0.4$ to $2$).

Comment: Dear YJT, what equilibrium has the payoff $0.4$ ? Could you please specify the mixed profiles giving the payoff $0.4$ ?

Comment: Also, how was the **complete mixedness** of equilibria used to employ the **indifference** ? I.e. what if one strategy had probability $0$ what would fail here, why we cannot use it ?

Comment: If a strategy has probability 0, it might be because it's payoff is smaller than the others. Only actions played with positive probability have the same payoff from indifference, so even if changing the probabilities to another fully mixed, the payoff will be still the same.

Comment: 0.4 is the completely mixed one, where Player 1 plays 2/5,1/5,2/5 and player 2 plays 1/5,2/5,2/5

Comment: Finally, how can I see that "In zero-sum all equilibria have the same payoff." How do I use the zero-sumness here ?

Comment: You can tackle it from many directions. For example: the minimax theorem (zero-sum games have a value). If there are two equilibria payoffs, which one is the value?

Comment: Finally about Mixed Nash Equilibria in non zero sum games, I got this hint: `in a non-zero sum game (A, B). In that case, P1’s mixed equilibrium strategy is determined by B, while , P2’s mixed equilibrium strategy is determined by A.` I would like to know and understand **why** P1's mixed equilibrium is determined by B and not A ??

Comment: Think about indifference.